# Two factor authentication -Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver4

I have build an IdentityServer4 server, which uses Asp.Net Identity. I have then enabled Two Factor Authentication for one of the user. I then checked to see that it has reflected the database.

Now, when I call,

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false)
```

It always returns RequiresTwoFactor as false. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what would be causing it.

Note:

I have also added the following lines of code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthVerification>();
services.AddTransient<ISmsSEnder, AuthVerification>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It turns out that I was missing the following code

```
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>()`

So it should be

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```